# Parsing values from JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I wish to get the value of consumptionSavings from the following JSON format stored as .txt file.

```
{
    "_id": "58edf905746de21c401a3dce",
    "sites": [{
        "ecms": [{
            "consumptionSavings": 148,
        "equipmentCost": 3455,
         {
            "energySource": "Electricity",
            "consumptionReduction": {
                "amount": 345435,
                "unit": "MWh"
            },
    "projectDurationMonths": 36
        }
    }

    }
    ]
]
}
```

I wrote the following code to extract the value of consumptionSavings;

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import json

data = json.load(open('data.txt'))

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[data["sites"]["ecms"]["consumptionSavings"]]})

wb = xw.Book('Values.xlsx')

ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

ws.range('C3').options(index=False).value = df

wb = xw.Book('Result.xlsx')

wb.save()

xw.apps[0].quit()
```

and It returns the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am bit confused how that could be. Thank you

Comment: `data['sites']` is a `list`, not a `dict`. You need to use `data['sites'][0]` instead. You may want to reformat your JSON to get a better picture of the structure.

Comment: Idem for data['sites'][0]["ecm"] - it's a list too.

Comment: @chepner Yes i got it. So for every '['  I needed to add [0]. Thank you.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[data["sites"][0]['ecms'][0]['consumptionSavings']]})`